# Adding custom data attribute for a new node in Jquery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to use the method `data` (jQuery 1.7.1) in this code:

```
var q = '<div class="form-error-marker"></div>';
var t = $(q).data('message', message).insertAfter(el);
```

and it does not work.

Note that this works:

```
var t = $(q).attr('data-message', message).insertAfter(el);
```

Why does the first variant not work?

EDIT: `insertAfter` works correctly and new div is added after `el` (which is instance of one element which I get by `getElementById()` function; long story short I have a library that I extend).

When I say 'it does not work' I mean that the attribute 'data-message' is not stored.

Comment: +1 I have the exact same issue.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does `el` contain more than one element?

Comment: SLaks: see the question update, please.

Comment: It **does** work. http://jsfiddle.net/7payvwgg/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `data` like that sets an arbitrary piece of data for this node; it doesn't add a new `data-` attribute.  Just add the attribute with the `attr` function, and then *access* it with `data`

```
var q = $('<div class="form-error-marker"></div>').attr("data-message", message);
```

Now access it like this:

```
var message = q.data("message");
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5je6V/)

Comment: "Using data like that sets an arbitrary piece of data for this node" I don't understand this sentence. What does it mean? Thanks!

Comment: @MartyIX - check out the docs for the data function http://api.jquery.com/data/  Basically, you can attach arbitrary data to any dom element with data('key', 'value').  You can retrieve these values by saying .data('key');  As of jQuery 1.4.3, saying .data('key') would not only look for previously set values set with .data('key', 'value') but would also look in html5 data attributes

Comment: This is not how `data()` should be used. OP's code works. The error was elsewhere or he/she is trying to access `attr('data-message')` after setting data, which is also wrong.

Comment: @popn - I've read your comment three times now and I have yet to make sense of it.  OP clearly thought .data would add an attribute, which I explained was incorrect.  Apparently he agreed since he saw fit to accept my answer.  And yes, .data CAN be used to read a data- attribute; I'm not sure why you think otherwise.

Comment: While you may set and get using `attr()`, you may as well use `attr('whatever')` instead of `attr('data-whatever')`. The code OP gave worked, he/she was using `$.data()` correctly. Now he/she is not.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `jQuery.data` you don't change element attributes, instead your data saved in `$.cache`.
So if you want to change element attributes use `jQuery.attr`, when you want to save some info use `jQuery.data`